# use-package can't load package at startup

Tags: init-file, use-package, start-up

When I start Emacs I get the error message

> Error (use-package): Cannot load counsel

But when I open `init.el` in a buffer and run `eval-buffer` everything works fine. What I'm doing wrong?

My Emacs config: https://git.sr.ht/~inquisitive/emacs-adjustments/tree/package/ivy/.emacs.d/init.el

```
;; Bootstrap straight.el
(defvar bootstrap-version)
(let ((bootstrap-file
       (expand-file-name "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el" user-emacs-directory))
      (bootstrap-version 5))
  (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file)
    (with-current-buffer
        (url-retrieve-synchronously
         "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raxod502/straight.el/develop/install.el"
         'silent 'inhibit-cookies)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (eval-print-last-sexp)))
  (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage))

(straight-use-package 'use-package)

(use-package magit
  :bind ("C-x g" . magit-status))

(use-package counsel
  :config
  (counsel-mode 1))

;; Display line numbers in programming major modes
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(menu-bar-mode nil)
 '(scroll-bar-mode nil)
 '(straight-use-package-by-default t)
 '(tool-bar-mode nil))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "#fcfcfc" :foreground "#232627" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 143 :width normal :foundry "FSD " :family "PragmataPro Mono Liga")))))
```

Comment: perhaps `counsel` isn't installed? try `M-x package-install <ret> counsel <ret>`

Comment: @manandearth: If the package isn't already installed it should be automatically installed with `straight.el`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the straight keyword in the use-package macro call e.g. add `:straight t`

From straight.el documentation https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el#integration-with-use-package

> To use use-package, first install it with straight.el:
>
> ```
> (straight-use-package 'use-package)
> ```
>
> Now use-package will use straight.el to automatically install missing packages if you provide :straight t:
>
> ```
> (use-package el-patch
>     :straight t)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the bug occurs because I set `straight-use-package-by-default` using the customize-interface. When I set the variable outside of `custom-set-variables` everything works fine.

Comment: I don't understand why that would be the case: can someone explain? A more likely reason to my mind is that the initialization of the variable has to happen earlier (e.g. before you use `straight-use-package` for the first time), but this is only a guess: I have not checked anything. OTOH, if you are right, I *really* would like to know why.

Answer (score -1):

In general you need to initialize the package system if you're going to use packages at init time.

i.e. Do this first:

```el
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(package-initialize)
```

(That said, I'd be slightly surprised if `use-package` didn't do that itself, so maybe this isn't the issue; but it's certainly worth testing it.)

Comment: OP is using straight.el and does not use package use-package can use both

Comment: Does `straight` have an equivalent to `package-initialize` then?

Comment: Yes it ius somethink like the bootstrap  code in the question - however I don't use it and don't know what the OP has miscopied or misunderstood

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I'll leave this answer here as extra information for others.